# Rails: How to make link_to use another attribute instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following line will create a link to `things/:id`

```
link_to "Thing", @thing
```

But I need to create a link to `things/:some_other_id`.

My first thought was that changing the route for `/things/:id` to `/things/:some_other_id` should work, but it didn't.

I need to do the following without explicitly indicating the `some_other_id` and `another_path`:

```
link_to "Thing", another_path(@thing.some_other_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a solution.  I need to override `Thing.to_param` which returns `Thing.id` by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
match "/things/:some_other_id" => "things#some_action"
```

you can define this in your routes file and placed it before the `resources :things` line.